# Take what's between [code][/code] and apply changes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to make code box, where I can apply changes. If I have this: `$var= "word";` inside these `[code]` HERE `[/code]`, I will change `$var` into red color and `"word"` into green.

I used `preg_replace` to select what's between these `[code]` `[/code]`.

```
$codebox = preg_replace("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/","$1",$string);
```

the thing is with preg_replace I can do outsider changes (to whole code). I want to do changes to what inside these `[code]` `[/code]`. Like: background color, all text color, all text font, all text font-weight and etc... that's mean I need to get it out apply changes then put it back.

I want to be able to use `str_replace` and `preg_replace` functions on `$1` not on `$string`.

for example to change`"word"` into green. I'll use

```
preg_replace("/(\".*?\")/","<span style='color: #090;'>$1</span>",$string)
```

and I can't use `preg_replace` inside `preg_replace`, can I?
I don't know if I'm using the wrong function here, or there is a way do this.

you may find my patterns wrong, correct me I just learnt them yesterday.

Comment: I think you want the [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = '[code]$var = "word";[/code]';
$codebox = preg_replace_callback("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/",function($m){
    // The following replacements are just a demo
    $m[1] = preg_replace('/"([^"]+)"/', '"<span style="color:#0D0;">$1</span>"', $m[1]); // green value
    $m[1] = preg_replace('/(\$\w+)/', '<span style="color:#F00;">$1</span>', $m[1]); // Red var name
    $m[1] = str_replace(' = ', '<span style="color:#00F;"> = </span>', $m[1]); // blue = sign
    return $m[1];
},$string);
echo $codebox;
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/VsuSeK).

Answer (score 2):

Targeting the code inside the tags is a bit simpler when you extract it first using `preg_match` instead of `preg_replace`:

```
$codebox = preg_match("/\[code\](.*)\[\/code\]/",$string,$matches);
$innercode = $matches[0];

// Then...

$innercode = preg_replace( ...

// Later on...

echo "[code]".$innercode."[/code]";
```

Your replaces return strings, so they can be nested just fine.

Also, I suggest looking at a text to regex converter if you're new to regular expressions. It helped me get a grasp on them better:

http://txt2re.com/index-php.php3?s=$bacon%20=%20%22good%22;&-21&2&6&-23&7&1&-22

Comment: that's cool. what if I had more than 1 code like `[code]` code 1 `[/code]` `[code]` code 2 `[/code]`... would it still works?

Comment: It should return each code box as another array item in that $matches array, so you could iterate through it using `foreach`.