# String replace multiple values

Tags: php, string

I have a string that looks like this:

> Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%

Is there a way to replace only the first two "%" (or the last two) so I can get the next output:

```
Bla bla <a href='link1'>yada yada</a> bla bla %yada yada%
```

and also, if necessary, the last two "%" so it outputs:

```
Bla bla <a href='link1'>yada yada</a> bla bla <a href='link2'>yada yada</a>
```

I can't figure out how to make the distinction between the first two and the last two so, if I want, I can be able to replace either the first or the last two marks "%" with a link.
I'm using php. Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: With your link identifier being `%`, it can cause a lot of errors a lot of different ways.  You can get creative with the [`strpos`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) function for it though.

Comment: Match with this regex: `/(%[^%]+%)/g`

Comment: u have to find first occurence then replace this and then find second occurnce then replace this

Comment: @Jon I don't necessarily have to use "%". I can mark it any way I want.

Comment: Then you _should_ come up with something that you are going to stick to that is more unique and you can create a good regular expression from.  BB Code was a good example of how to format something in that fashion and allow for expression replacement. ^^

Comment: @MayurKukadiya What if I want to chage the 5th and the 6th occurence in a string? I can't eliminate the first 4 since I might have to replace them too at a later time.

Comment: is the content inside the %% always the same?  or does it vary ?

Comment: @aleation It varies. It's in different languages so the text between the %% has to remain the same. And I don't know or have control over it. All I have to do is transform it into a "linkable" text without changing it

Comment: @Kapn0batai...Check my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex **(PHP 5.3+ required)** :

```
$string = 'Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%';
echo preg_replace('/%([^%]*)%/', '<a href="http://example.com">$1</a>', $string, 1) . '<br>'; // to replace the first instance.
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ //
$links = array('http://example.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com', 'http://google.com');
$index = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/%([^%]*)%/', function($m) use($links, &$index){
    $m[1] = '<a href="'.$links[$index].'">'.$m[1].'</a>';
    $index++;
    // reset the index if it exceeds (N links - 1)
    if($index >= count($links)){
        $index = 0;
    }
    return $m[1];
}, $string).'<br>'; // to replace according to your array
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ //
// To test with a string that contains more %% than the links
$string2 = 'Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada% wuuut dsfsf %yada yada% sjnfsf %yada yada% jnsfds';
$links = array('http://example.com', 'http://stackoverflow.com', 'http://google.com');
$index = 0;
echo preg_replace_callback('/%([^%]*)%/', function($m) use($links, &$index){
    $m[1] = '<a href="'.$links[$index].'">'.$m[1].'</a>';
    $index++;
    // reset the index if it exceeds (N links - 1)
    if($index >= count($links)){
        $index = 0;
    }
    return $m[1];
}, $string2).'<br>'; // to replace according to your array
```

[Online demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fIitVS).

Comment: Works, but on some (older) servers you will get the T_FUNCTION error. To fix this you will need to name your function an then call it like this: `preg_replace_callback('/%([^%]*)%/','my_function',$string)`. Example: http://codepad.org/zUMXvbEN

Comment: @Jules I know, this is assuming you're using **PHP 5.3+**

Comment: In this manner wouldn't I have to know the text between the %% ? Because that is my problem... I can't mess with the actual text since there are many strings in many different languages. All I have to do is make it linkable.

Comment: @Kapn0batai You wouldn't have to know what's between the `%%` **but** you will have unwanted results if it contains a `%` !

Comment: @Kapn0batai If you're not sure whether there is a `%` between `%%`, then you maybe should take the BB code approach like Jon said. With that said, I have a little (close) [example here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16113779/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
***Support for PHP 4 and PHP 5***

---

**Solution:**

```
$string ='Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%';

// Count no of %
$count = substr_count($string,'%');

// Valid string pattern
if ( 0 == ($count % 2) ) {

    $urlString = $string;
    
    // Iterate for each pair of % to make it link
    for ( $i=1; $i <= $count/2 ; $i++  ) {
    
        $urlString = preg_replace('/%/', "<a href='link$i'>", $urlString, 1);
        $urlString = preg_replace('/%/', "</a>", $urlString, 1);
    }
}
// Invalid string pattern
else {
    echo "Invalid string pattern";
}

// Display generated link 
echo $urlString;
```

---

**Working of preg_replace function**

- **Remove first two %**

```
    $str ='Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%';
    $newStr = preg_replace('/%/', '', $str, 2);
    
    echo $newStr;
    
    // Output => Bla bla yada yada bla bla %yada yada%
```

---

- **Remove last two %**

```
    $str ='Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%';
    $newStr = preg_replace('/%/', '', strrev($str), 2);
    $newStr =  strrev($newStr);
    
    echo $newStr;
    
    // Output => Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla yada yada
```

---

- **Remove all %**

```
    $str ='Bla bla %yada yada% bla bla %yada yada%';
    $newStr = preg_replace('/%/', '', $str);
    
    echo $newStr;
    
    // Output => Bla bla yada yada bla bla yada yada
```

---

Reference
https://www.php.net/preg%5Freplace

Comment: There's no pattern, and it doesn't allow for the opening or closing of the `a` tag.

Comment: If only a link, should be a comment.