# Regular expression to match after first % and before last %

Tags: php, regex, parsing, html-parsing, substitution

I need a regular expression that can match what is inside the "%" marks in the following string:

> 1) Bla bla bla %yada yada yada% bla bla.

Even if the form is like this:

> 2) Bla bla bla %yada yada yada% bla bla %yada #1 yada%

I thought that `/%([^%]*)%/` would do but in the second case it doesn't match the second part (%yada #1 yada%), only the first.

The expression has to match even if the substring between the "%" marks contains something like "#1". Thank you in advance

Regards

> 

```
function replace($search, $replace, $subject, $link)
    {
        if (preg_match('/#[1-9]/', $search) == 1 && $link == null)
        {
            echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
        }
        if (preg_match('/%[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+%/', $search) == 1 && $link != null && $replace == null)
        {
            echo preg_replace('/%[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+%/', '<a href=$link>$1</a>', $subject, 1) . '<br>';
        }
    }

$string = 'bla bla #1 bla bla %bla bla% bla #2 %bla bla #3 bla%';
$newString = replace('/%[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+%/', null, $string, 'www.google.com');
echo $newString;
preg_match('/%[a-zA-Z0-9# ]+%/', $newString)); // 0 = no match
```

So on this second call I don't get a match. Hope this helps.

Comment: do you want to match `yada yada yada% bla bla %yada #1 yada` or `yada yada yada` and `yada #1 yada` with the second test?

Comment: Do you want one extracted substring, or several?  Consider `X%A%B%C%Y`. Do you want the three internal strings `A`,`B`,`C` to be pulled out or do you just want `A%B%C` pulled out? From you comment on one of the answers, it very much looks like you want there to be three matches, so that you can do some sort of `s/foo/bar/g` magic on each of them.

Comment: @tchrist his example suggests only `A` and `C` in your example.

Comment: @MaPePeR The first time I call my function (on the second example) it has to match "yada yada yada". The function will replace the "%" marks with something like:`<a href="link">yada yada yada</a>` The secont time I call it it should do the same for "yada #1 yada". So when I call it the second time it replaces the last two "%" remaining marks with: `<a href="another link">yada #1 yada</a>`

Comment: @Loamhoof I wish we had actual data to look at. The faked up stuff is difficult to get a good feel for. If what he is actually doing is is extracting parenthesized substring, as I begin to suspect, then yes, that is a different problem.

Comment: @Kapn0batai edit your question to add the relevant part of your code.

Comment: are you modifying a html document in place using Javascript? If that is the case you might have other problems than a (not)-broken Regex. By inserting a element into `innerHTML`, `innerHTML` will not contain the string anymore.

Comment: @Loamhoof is right: you need to supply actual expected inputs and outputs. You had also better add a language tag to say what programming language or tool or program you expect this to work under.

Comment: **Fun fact**: I already answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16186685/) with a dynamic solution. So why didn't you post a feedback ?

Comment: @Kapn0batai your code has a lot of problems which don't concern your regex. See my edit for a beginning...

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I can't use your dynamic solution. But using your expression preg_match returns 0 the secont time I call it. I thought it was because of the #1 inside the marks.

Comment: @Kapn0batai Of course it will return nothing (or do nothing) for the second time since all the `%%` should have been replaced.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV The first time I call it it replaces the first two "%". So `echo $newString; //outputs: bla bla #1 bla bla bla bla bla #2 %bla bla #3 bla%`. Now, when I use preg_match on $newString, using the same regex it finds no match.

Answer (score 1):

See your calls to `preg_match`... The second argument should be `$subject` not `$search`...

Also, use `return` to actually return something, not `echo`.

Comment: I have a function that is called one time for every replacement. So, I call the function once and it replaces the first substring. The second time I call it (the 3rd and 4th "%" marks are still in the string) it finds no match. I thought it has to do with the "#1" positioned inside the marks.

Comment: I don't think so in fact. I misread his examples (or did he change it?). This ain't a solution. @Kapn0batai could you add your code? I think it'd help.

Comment: Oh drat! I hate it when that happens. Yes, this is some sort of ugly php ad-hockery.

Comment: The preg_match only identifies the string I'm using as a parameter. That's why the function has two "if"s. So the second argument is $subject because I want to know, when the function is called, what is the tipe of the replacement that must occur. The function has to be able to replace not only what is between the "%" but also #1 or #2 contained by the same string if called again.

Answer (score 1):

`%.*%`

This will match

1) a %

2) any number of any characters

3) a %

And since it will match greedily rather than lazily, it will match the widest %...% it can, rather than stop at the first.

For example, the lazy version of this would be %.*?% (putting ? after a * makes it lazy) and it would close after the first, not last %.

Answer (score 0):

`/%.+?%/` should do the trick.
See greedyness of regex expressions.
`[^%]` stops at the first `%`. But you want to include all characters between the two `%`s.

Comment: `.+?`, do  you mean `.*` ?

Comment: No, that won’t work. Consider `X%A%B%C%Y` — he wants to pull out three matches from that `A`, `B`, and `C`, and you pattern will not do that, since you will only find `A` and `C` that way.

Comment: There is a difference between `.+?` and `.*`. `.*` is greedy and `.+?` being lazy. `.*?` can be used when you also want to match `%%`.

Comment: @tchrist this is unclear from the question. i expected to match `%A% %B%` to `A`,`B`. I don't understand the question like you did.

Comment: @MaPePeR but anyway, his regex should work. Yours is just slower. I think we won't see his problem till his put his code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression

```
%[a-zA-Z0-9# ]*%
```

Hope it helps